# ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans

Доброго времени суток! Учусь работать в среде netbeans IDE 8.1 на ubuntu.
Не удается запустить даже простейшую программу при нажатии на f6. Как это можно исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какой язык вы пытаетесь изучить?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman c++

Comment: скорей всего у вас NetBeans не настроен. и NetBeans больше ориентирован на Java.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman не подскажете, как настроить?

Comment: подскажу - [Установка и настройка поддержки C/C++](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions_ru.html)